# How can I stop Chrome from showing recent searches?

Tags: google-chrome, history, google-account

I want to save the history. Disabling everything is not a choice.

I just use the same google account on my work PC and on my private PC. When I click into the search bar of a new tab, it shows me a dropdown of recent searches - including private searches from yesterday evening. When I share my screen, my colleagues see this and might think that I've been looking for all this during work time.

How can I fix this? Do I need seperate accounts for work/private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah perhaps considering getting a separate account as manually clicking 'remove' for each search term in the drop-down can be consuming or the other option is to go to search history in google settings and clear for 'all-time'